# EF4.1 Include doesn't work if you instantiate non-list association property in constructor

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have some simple Code First classes with a Many to One relationship. If I retrieve a Child and use Include to retrieve the School, then it works OK if I comment out the School = new School() line, but with it in, the School class is not populated. I assume that this is expected behaviour (can someone confirm?), but it caught me out, especially given that doing the same with a collection property works fine.

```
public class Child
{
    public Child()
    {
        School = new School();    
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }        
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }        
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }        
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        var context = new TestContext("...connectionstring...");

        var child = context.Children.Include(x => x.School).Where(x => x.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();

        Debug.Assert(child.School.Id != 0, "School is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, instantiating reference navigation properties in the default constructur causes trouble:

- [EF 4.1 Code First: Why is EF not setting this navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060602/270591)
- [What would cause the Entity Framework to save an unloaded (but lazy loadable) reference over existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779226/what-would-cause-the-entity-framework-to-save-an-unloaded-but-lazy-loadable-ref/6780912#6780912)

It works fine for collections because you are just instantiating an empty collection in this case but not any referenced objects. But you better avoid to do this for a reference property.