# Code First Object not properly instantiating

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have  a class department inheriting from activeentity

```
public class ActiveEntity : Entity, IActive
    {
        public ActiveEntity()
        {
            IsActive = true;
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        [Timestamp, ScaffoldColumn(false), DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string CreationUserId { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string LastModifiedUserId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Department:ActiveEntity    
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.Address = new DepartmentAddress();
        }
        [StringLength(9),MinLength(9),MaxLength(9)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid ManagerId { get; set; }
        [UIHint("AjaxDropdown")]
        public User Manager { get; set; }
        public Guid? AddressId { get; set; }
        public DepartmentAddress Address { get; set; }

        public ICollection<OverheadRate> OverheadRates { get; set; }


    }
```

I am just using annotations no Fluent API. The data saves to the data Sql Server 2008 just fine however the address object never gets instantiated, even though I have the context use the include

```
return c.Set<Department>().Include(d => d.Address).Include(d => d.Manager).Where(predicate);
```

The data is returned I run sql profiler and then run the query it returns the correct data.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove instantiating the address (`this.Address = new DepartmentAddress();`) in the `Department` constructor. Instantiating navigation references in the default constructor is evil and has nasty side effects like these:

[What would cause the Entity Framework to save an unloaded (but lazy loadable) reference over existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779226/what-would-cause-the-entity-framework-to-save-an-unloaded-but-lazy-loadable-ref/6780912#6780912)

[EF 4.1 Code First: Why is EF not setting this navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060602/ef-4-1-code-first-why-is-ef-not-setting-this-navigation-property/7071882#7071882)