# EF Fluent API many to one relation, navigation property is not fetched

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent, entity-framework-5

I have a database with the Entity Framework 5 RC (with Fluent API) working now, but I can't seem to get a specific relation to work. And it is driving me nuts for the past few nights I'm working on it.

It is the following relation:

[Link to the database diagram](http://roetje.home.xs4all.nl/static/ExerciseRelation.png)

As you can see, I have a `Exercise` which is related to an `ExerciseType`. The problem is, the `Exercise.ExerciseType` navigation property, is not loaded. The relation I made is as follows:

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Exercise>
...
this.HasRequired(ex => ex.ExerciseType)
    .WithMany(exType => exType.Exercises)
    .HasForeignKey(ex => ex.ExerciseTypeId);
```

The problem is that there is no error for me to google on. The entities are fetched, but the related `EntityType` property on the `Exercise` objects, is never fetched.

I am using the following query to force the `ExerciseType` to be fetched, but that doesn't seem to make it work either.

```
    List<Exercise> exs = db.Exercises.Include(t => t.ExerciseType).ToList();
```

Is there someting wrong with the relationship I created? Or is there something wrong with the database configuration perhaps?

Code for the entities:

```
public class ExerciseType
{
    public int ExerciseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ExerciseTypeName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
}

public class Exercise
{
    public Exercise()
    {
        this.ExerciseTemplateMembers = new List<ExerciseTemplateMember>();
        this.TrainingSchemeMembers = new List<TrainingSchemeMember>();
        this.ExerciseType = new ExerciseType();
    }

    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public int ExerciseTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ExerciseName { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionHowTo { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionResult { get; set; }
    public byte[] ExerciseImage1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] ExerciseImage2 { get; set; }
    public string ExerciseVideoUrl { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExerciseTemplateMember> ExerciseTemplateMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TrainingSchemeMember> TrainingSchemeMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ExerciseType ExerciseType { get; set; }
}

    public ExerciseMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ExerciseId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseName)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.DescriptionHowTo)
            .HasMaxLength(250);

        this.Property(t => t.DescriptionResult)
            .HasMaxLength(250);

        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseVideoUrl)
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Exercise");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseId).HasColumnName("ExerciseId");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseTypeId).HasColumnName("ExerciseTypeId");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseName).HasColumnName("ExerciseName");
        this.Property(t => t.DescriptionHowTo).HasColumnName("DescriptionHowTo");
        this.Property(t => t.DescriptionResult).HasColumnName("DescriptionResult");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseImage1).HasColumnName("ExerciseImage1");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseImage2).HasColumnName("ExerciseImage2");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseVideoUrl).HasColumnName("ExerciseVideoUrl");
        this.Property(t => t.Enabled).HasColumnName("Enabled");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(ex => ex.ExerciseType)
            .WithMany(exType => exType.Exercises)
            .HasForeignKey(ex => ex.ExerciseTypeId);
    }

    public ExerciseTypeMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ExerciseTypeId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseTypeName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ExerciseType");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseTypeId).HasColumnName("ExerciseTypeId");
        this.Property(t => t.ExerciseTypeName).HasColumnName("ExerciseTypeName");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy");
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. Strange problem. Is the `ExerciseTypeId` not nullable in the database and do you have an enforced foreign key constraint for the relationship in the DB? Do the exercises refer to existing exercisetypes in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** this line from the `Exercise` constructor:

```
this.ExerciseType = new ExerciseType();
```

Instantiating navigation reference properties in the default constructor causes all sorts of strange problems, like this for example: [What would cause the Entity Framework to save an unloaded (but lazy loadable) reference over existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779226/what-would-cause-the-entity-framework-to-save-an-unloaded-but-lazy-loadable-re) Or this: [EF 4.1 Code First: Why is EF not setting this navigation property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060602/ef-4-1-code-first-why-is-ef-not-setting-this-navigation-property)

Comment: This indeed solved the problem. When I was building the relations with `ICollection` types as property, I thought this was not harmful. Now I know that I can with ICollections, and can't with single entities. Or do I need to remove the other two initializations too? Because they work properly as far as I know. Thank you for your help and insight.

Comment: @Roet: Creating the empty collections is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide code of `EntityType` class? I had same problem with EF 4.3.1 today when I forgot to make the property (`ExerciseType` in your case) **virtual**. If that's not the case, please provide code of the class after all.

If you use lazy loading feature your entities have to have navigation properties marked virtual. EF generates proxy class inheriting from your entity, and if the property is not virtual, the derived class cannot provide it's own implementation of that property (implementation which should load related object/collection lazily).

Comment: I have them marked virtual, as I am aware of that. But you have a good point none the less. I added the code of the entities to the question, you might notice something else.