# Fluent API many to one relation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a simple case. User has many topics, and topics have one user. So

```
public class Users
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Topics> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topics
{
    public Topics()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tags>();
        Answers = new HashSet<Answers>();
        User = new Users();
    }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

I get user topics in fluent API. One to Many

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasMany(u => u.Topics).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
```

But I cannot reach Topic's user.name  which is many to one relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just removed `User = new Users();` from constructor and it worked..
Did not carefully checkout this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197546/ef-fluent-api-many-to-one-relation-navigation-property-is-not-fetched?rq=1)