# Entity Framework 4.3.1 not populating child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using the repository pattern, I have a generic repository `EFRepository` of type T (using generics).

I have a method called `AllIncluding` that is used to fetch an entity and any child entities thereof:

```
public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, 
                                  object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Using the following syntax in the call:

```
_machineRepository.AllIncluding(machine => machine.InstalledOS, 
                                machine => machine.LicenceType, 
                                machine => machine.User);
```

My Machine class looks like this (with some details ommitted):

```
public class Machine
{
    public int MachineId { get; set; }

    public int InstalledOSId { get; set; }
    public InstalledOS InstalledOS { get; set; }

    public int LicenceTypeId { get; set; }
    public LicenceType LicenceType { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm finding is that at the time I render the View (using ASP.NET MVC 4 beta) for the Machine entity, the Installed OS and Licence Type entities are not populated, they seem to be instantiated but the ID is 0 and the other properties are null. In the Machine entity directly, the InstalledOSId and LicenceTypeId properties are populated with the correct Ids.

If I debug the application all the way down to the AllIncluding method I can see that the constructed SELECT query contains the correct tables and joins but still, no dice.

I'm not sure if its of any consequence but I'm passing back IQueryable all the way up to the controller. I'm assuming that the view rendering (return View(results)) can manage the enumeration?

Comment: Few things : 1. I'm not sure that `object` in  `Expression<Func<T, object>>` is appreciated by EF. 2. the navigation properties in your model are not virtual. 3. Try to make a ToList() after your call, and get the error (if you've got one).

Comment: Is the PK of LicenceType and InstalledOS really an int too?

Comment: @mfussenegger, yes all Ids of entities are ints.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus; 1. code has been generated by scaffolding, what would you suggest to replace it with? 2. I've gone through and made all child entities in all entities virtual, 3. doing a ToList doesn't generate errors it just gives me a list of machines with no child entities loaded.

Comment: Just checking your context contains DbSet entries for the InstalledOS and LicenceType entities?

Comment: What are the "omitted details"? For example, do you have a default constructor in the `Machine` class which instantiates the `InstalledOS` and `LicenceType` navigation properties?

Comment: @Slauma yes, the default constructor for Machine instantiates these properties by calling their default constructor which I guess nulls the name and zeroes the ID.

Comment: @Richard, yes entries for both exist in the context.

Comment: Remove the instantiation of the navigation references from the `Machine` constructor. It results in a lot of trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6780912/270591 (and there were some more questions about strange problems caused by this...)

Comment: @Slauma - this appears to have been the problem! I've removed the constructors all together because they weren't doing anything special anyway and I can now see the entities being populated and ultimately being displayed on the front end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple implementation of what you've said here that works - perhaps you can compare it to what you have to find the differences:

```
public class Machine
{
    public int MachineId { get; set; }

    public int InstalledOSId { get; set; }
    public InstalledOS InstalledOS { get; set; }

    public int LicenceTypeId { get; set; }
    public LicenceType LicenceType { get; set; }
}

public class InstalledOS
{
    public int InstalledOSId { get; set; }
}

public class LicenceType
{
    public int LicenceTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LicenceType> LicenceTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InstalledOS> InstalledOSs { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbSet<T> _dbSet;
    public Repository(DbSet<T> dbset)
    {
        _dbSet = dbset;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, 
                                      object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
        Context context = new Context();

        InstalledOS os1 = new InstalledOS();
        context.InstalledOSs.Add(os1);

        LicenceType l1 = new LicenceType();
        context.LicenceTypes.Add(l1);

        Machine m1 = new Machine
        {
            InstalledOS = os1, 
            LicenceType = l1
        };
        context.Machines.Add(m1);

        context.SaveChanges();

        Repository<Machine> repo = new Repository<Machine>(context.Machines);

        var query = repo.AllIncluding(m => m.InstalledOS, m => m.LicenceType);
        Machine m2 = query.First();

        Console.WriteLine(m2.InstalledOS.InstalledOSId);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```